# Joining Tables in Entity Framework correct syntax query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, syntax

I'm trying to make a join in EF in an efficient way, using two tables. Table1 and Table2

I'm currently doing two queries and able to consolidate the data later, which is working without issue, but I'm trying to condense it into a single query with no luck so far. Here are the separate queries:

```
var data1 = Context.Table1.Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.ObjectId)).OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
```

This gets me all columns from Table1

```
var data2 = data1.Join(Context.Table2, a => a.ObjectId, b => b.ObjectId, (a, b) => b)
.Select(x => new { x.ObjectId, x.OtherThing });
```

This gets me the extra field I need from Table2

These give me 2 data sets with a matching id that I can then combine with a foreach, but I know there is a way to get that all consolidated with 1 query, but can't get the logic / syntax after looking at many posts.

Here's what I've been trying in terms of a single query:

```
var data1 = Context.Table1.Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.ObjectId)).OrderBy(x => x.Order)
.Join(Context.Table2, a => a.ObjectId, b => b.ObjectId, (a, b) => b)
.Select(x => new { x.ObjectId, x.OtherThing });
.ToList();
```

```
var data1 = Context.Table1.Join(Context.Table2, a => a.ObjectId, b => b.ObjectId, (a, b) => b)
.Select(x => new { x.ObjectId, x.OtherThing })
.Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.ObjectId)).OrderBy(x => x.Order);
.ToList();
```

I'm expecting to get a single data object that has all columns from Table1 and 1 additional column from table 2.

Anyone able to highlight what I'm doing wrong?  Any help at all is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the part `(a, b) => b`. That's where you can project to a type containing both `a` and `b` properties.

Comment: I've tried something like that too, where I'll use 

               .Select( dto  => new Table1Table2Dto() {
                RowId = dto.RowId,
                Info = dto.Info
                }

etc.... but it moans for any of the values that don't exist in table2,  even if they do exist in the Dto object

Comment: and if I try (b, a) => b.... or   (a, b) => a

then the same thing happens, however it's the opposite fields (i.e. Columns not existing in table1) that VS moans about

Comment: ` (b, a) => new { a.Prop1, b.Prop2 }`

Comment: that helped! thank you very much. have a lovely Christmas